# how to remove back button in the toolbar of top level fragment if I set toolbar in each fragment using navigation component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have tried to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57168882/how-to-remove-back-button-from-toolbar-when-using-bottom-menu-bar-with-navigatio) but my problem is little bit different.

I need some different toolbars, so according the documentation from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations) , I need to set the toolbar in each of my fragment not in my MainActivity.

so I set the toolbar in each xml of my fragment. and then in each fragment I use this code to set the toolbar

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val toolbar = view.findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar3)

        val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navHostFragment)


    }
```

but I have back button in top level fragment of my bottom navigation view like the image below. I am confused how to pass appBarConfiguration if I set the toolbar from my fragment not from my MainActivity

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I finally get the answer. I need to set `appBarConfiguration` in EACH top level fragment

so in my `HomeFragment` and in `SearchFragment`, you should it like this

```
val toolbar = view.findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar2)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
    R.id.destination_home,
    R.id.destination_search)
)

val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navHostFragment,appBarConfiguration)
```

to use `AppBarConfiguration` class , you need `navigation-ui-ktx` artifact and also in gradle app you use pass this compile options and kotlin options

```
android {


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

}
```

Comment: This is also needed if you have multi-module project. But you need to have navigation in one separate module holding nav_graphs that are visible to each other.

Answer (score -1):

**You should try the CUSTOM ACTION BAR instead default ACTION BAR and In which fragment you don't want to back Button Just set VISIBILITY GONE.**